# For Loop with Google Geocoding - High Error Rate - iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, mkmapview, geocoding

I am using the below code to fetch location information via Geocoding and then add a map pin to a Google Map View. The code uses a For loop to cycle through each place in my database. The problem is that the code fails to return location info for about 50% of the places when run. These failed items are saved in the failedLoad array as per the code below.

Can anyone suggest why this is ? Also since these failed items are saved in the "failedLoad" array, is there a way I could use this array to load any missing pins ?

EDIT

The failed items are due to a 620 error which means that I am submitting items too quickly. How can I add a delay into the code ?

Thanks !

```
-(void)displayPlaces {


for (PlaceObject *info in mapLocations) {

        // GET ANNOTATION INFOS
        NSString * addressOne = info.addressOne;
        NSString * name = info.name;
        NSString * postCode = info.postCode;

        NSString * addressTwo = [addressOne stringByAppendingString:@",London,"];
        NSString * address = [addressTwo stringByAppendingString:postCode];

       NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv", [address stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
       NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
       NSURLRequest* req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

       OHURLLoader* loader = [OHURLLoader URLLoaderWithRequest:req];
       [loader startRequestWithCompletion:^(NSData* receivedData, NSInteger httpStatusCode) {
           NSString* locationString = loader.receivedString;
           NSArray *listItems = [locationString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

        double latitude = 0.0;
        double longitude = 0.0;

        if([listItems count] >= 4 && [[listItems objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"200"]) {
            latitude = [[listItems objectAtIndex:2] doubleValue];
            longitude = [[listItems objectAtIndex:3] doubleValue];

        }

        else {

            NSLog(@"Error %@",name);
            [failedLoad addObject : info];

        }  


        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
        coordinate.latitude = latitude;
        coordinate.longitude = longitude;
        MyLocation *annotation = [[[MyLocation alloc] initWithName:name address:address coordinate:coordinate] autorelease];

        [mapViewLink addAnnotation:annotation];

       } errorHandler:^(NSError *error) {
           NSLog(@"Error while downloading %@: %@",url,error);
       }];

 }


}
```

Comment: There are various query rate limits on the Google API, e.g. max 10 requests per second. You should really RTFM on all this if you plan to use the API.

Comment: When a location fails to load, why don't you log the string that was returned.  It will then be immediately obvious why it fails.

Comment: Thanks - it's a 620 error which I understand is due to the rate I'm submitting at. How would I put a delay in the code ?

Comment: Note that this question is [the followup of this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628464/efficiency-of-google-geocoding-with-dispatch-queue-how-to-improve-iphone) (but this is **not** a duplicate, as the present question is about Google API rate limits and adding delays between requests -- just mentionned this previous post for those who are interested about how we got to that code)

Comment: Thanks Ali - I appreciate your help with improving the efficiency of the code. I guess I need to add in a delay to your custom class.

Comment: If I remember well the Google Maps Web service allows to aggregate multiple requests in one call (I could be wrong). Have a look at http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/webservices/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a for loop and send all your requests at the same time, you probably should send them one after the other (or 5 by 5?)

Here is one way to do it *(not tested in real code, just typed as I go so may have some typo)*:

```
// In the instance variables, have:
@property(retain) NSMutableSet* mapLocationsToGeocode;

// When you want to decode, use:
self.mapLocationsToGeocode = [NSMutableSet setWitharray:mapLocations];
// (Or add to the existing NSSet if you have one and add Places using multple passes)
[self popLocationAndGeocode];

-(void)popLocationAndGeocode
{
  // Pop any location from the set
  PlaceObject* onePlace = [mapLocationsToGeocode anyObject];

  // Build the URL given the PlaceObject
  NSString* address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,London,%@",info.addressOne,info.postCode];
  NSString* name = info.name;

  NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv", [address stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  NSURLRequest* req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];

  // Remove it so it won't be poped again
  [mapLocationsToGeocode removeObject:onePlace];

  // Send the request here to decode the PlaceObject
  OHURLLoader* loader = [OHURLLoader URLLoaderWithRequest:req];
  [loader startRequestWithCompletion:^(NSData* receivedData, NSInteger httpStatusCode) {
    NSString* locationString = loader.receivedString;
    NSArray* listItems = [locationString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    ...

    if([listItems count] >= 4 && [[listItems objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"200"]) {
        // Process with latitude and longitude, add your MKAnnotation, etc
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error %@",name);
        [failedPlaces addObject:onePlace];
    }  
    ...

     // Schedule the next decoding request (1)
     if ([mapLocationsToGeocode count]) [self performSelector:@selector(popLocationAndGeocode) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
   } errorHandler:^(NSError *error) {
       NSLog(@"Error while downloading %@: %@",url,error);
       [failedPlaces addObject:onePlace];

       // Schedule the next decoding request anyway (1)
       if ([mapLocationsToGeocode count]) [self performSelector:@selector(popLocationAndGeocode) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
   }];

   // Schedule the next decoding request (2) -- solution 2
   // if ([mapLocationsToGeocode count]) [self performSelector:@selector(popLocationAndGeocode) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0]; // wait one sec before sending next request
}
```

Of course, dont forget to set the property back to nil when done (or in the `dealloc`) to release the memory.

In case (1), I call `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay` in both the completion and error blocks, so that the next request/decoding process is called only once the first has finished. This way your requests are somewhat serialized.

In case (2) (commented/disabled), I call `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay` right after the `startRequestWithCompletion:...` method, so it won't wait for the end of the first request to pop the next one. But you will wait (hopefully) long enough so that you won't reach the GoogleAPI rate limit

---

Note that this is not the only solution, there are plenty other possibilities. One being to use `NSOperationQueue` to queue the requests one after the other on a queue and add dependencies to it, or schedule the sending process of the requests on a GCD serial queue (yeah, I know I told you not to use GCD to actually *send* your requests, but that still apply, still dont use GCD+synchronous requests, but you can use GCD to queue blocks that will call `[OHURLLoader startRequestWithCompletion:...]` on the main thread one after the other; the request itself still being executed on the main thread by the RunLoop)

Comment: Thank you - that seems to work well. However the app crashes when it has finished adding pins. How do I stop the selector / timer once the mapLocationsToGeocode array is empty ?

Comment: Ok fixed with :     [self performSelector:@selector(popLocationAndGeocode) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.15];
    
    int x = [mapLocationsToGeocode count];
    
    if (x<=1) {
    
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(popLocationAndGeocode) object:nil];

    }

Comment: Oh yeah forgot the stop condition ;) Instead of scheduling the "performSelector" request then cancelling right after, you should not schedule it at all, namely use `if ([mapLocationsToGeocode count]) [self performSelector:... withObject:nil afterDelay:...]`

Comment: Bec careful too if you choose solution (2) instead of (1) (and uncomment the line), there is an issue I just spotted: you may try to pop the same PlaceObject twice, if the next call to `popLocationAndGeocode` (and `[mapLocationsToGeocode anyObject]` call) executes before the pending request has finished (namely before the `[mapLocationsToGeocode removeObject:onePlace]` call of the first request is reached). You may remove the object from the set right after the call to anyObject (but in that case don't forget to retain it before removing it from the set to avoid it being deallocated too soon!)

Comment: _Edited my code to hopefully fix the issue I was talking about in last comment_